# How do I fetch PHP script output from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

This is an example of the PHP script I want to get the output from within my javascript file:

### data.php

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents('data.txt');
echo $input."\n";

?>
```

### script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data;
    // get output from data.php
    console.log( data );
});
```

I just want a way to test to see if the data from within the data.txt file that is being stored in a php variable can be passed into the javascript file and then printed within the javascript console on the html page.

I want to do this so that I can store a variable in the text file and then reference it as it dynamically is updated from multiple users at the same time.

I've seen ways to do this, but it involves the javascript being in the same file as the html, which is not the case here. I'm also using jquery so I don't know if that makes a difference. I've never used php before and am new to javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put you php code in the javascript file if you change the extension to "php". As "php" extensions will get delivered as Html per default, you have to state that it is Javascript in the code.

script.js.php

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
?>console.log("<?php

$input = file_get_contents('data.txt');
echo $input."\n";

 ?>");
$(document).ready(function(){


 $("#imgTag, #img2").on("click", process);

 var size = 0;

 function getTarget(evt)
 {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    return evt.target || evt.scrElement;
  }

  var temp;
  console.log("before get");
  console.log("post get");
  console.log(size);

  function changeSize(myName, myOther)
  {
     var name = myName;
    var other = myOther;
    if($("#" + name).height() < 400)
    {
       $("#" + name).height($("#" + name).height() + 5);
       $("#" + name).width($("#" + name).width() + 5);
       $("#" + other).height($("#" + other).height() - 5);    
       $("#" + other).width($("#" + other).width() - 5);   
    }    
  }

  function process(event)
  {
     var name = getTarget(event).id;
     var other;
     if(name == "imgTag")
     {
        other = "img2";
     }
    else
      other = "imgTag";

console.log($("#" + name));
console.log("Changing size!!!");
console.log( $("#" + name).height());
changeSize(name, other);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read that text file directly with jquery like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : "data.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            // Display the data in console
            console.log(data);
            // Or append it to body
            $('body').append(data);
        }
    });
```

The same way you can read output from your php file, in which case you should change the url to point to your php file. Another thing you should read about is different options of communicating server-client side like json data structure etc. 
Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/